# Populating an Array from Core Data in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsarray

I am trying to populate an **NSArray** with a collection of data I get from CoreData. But my array doesnt seem to be populating with the data. I have the following code to retrieve the data:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]
                                initWithEntityName:@"WeightLog"];
self.contactarray = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                         error:nil] mutableCopy];
```

And I am using the following for loop to populate the NSArray with the data I collect from WeightLog for a particular field.

```
for (int i =0; i<=self.contactarray.count; i++) {
    NSManagedObject *device = [self.contactarray objectAtIndex:i];
    [titleNames addObject:device];
}
```

Just so you know **contactarray** is a property in my .h file of the following format:

```
@property (strong) NSMutableArray *contactarray;
```

Can you tell me where I am going wrong please, I am fairly new to iOS Development, if it doesn't show.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does your `executeFetchRequest` call return correct array? Pass `NSError` parameter instead of `nil` and check if you are getting any errors. A side note: You don't need to create a `mutableCopy` of array to iterate over. Also the `for` loop seems unnecessary since your are just duplicating same `contactarray`.

Comment: Where is `titleNames` declared, and initialised?

Comment: titleNames is declared in my .h file as
    NSMutableArray *titleNames;
And in the loop is when it is first used.

Comment: The executeFetchRequest does return the data I need, it just doesn't pass it into the NSMutableArray.

Comment: Can you post the code? I can't see it being initialised, which would explain the array not containing anything.

Comment: @StephenBennett You need to initialise `titleNames` before use.

Comment: Take a look at MagicalRecord, it makes Core Data so much easier..

Comment: Looking at your question again and the answer; Why are you taking the array you get from your fetch request, copying it, and then taking each value one at a time and adding it to another array? What's wrong with just using the copy of the array you have in the first place?

Comment: Because I wanted to keep a copy of them as I am populating the data into a CollectionViewController. Is this not the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialise `titleNames` array before use. Try this,

```
titleNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i =0; i<=self.contactarray.count; i++) {
    NSManagedObject *device = [self.contactarray objectAtIndex:i];
    [titleNames addObject:device];
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Akhilrajtr that was it! Really appreciate it! I also forgot 1 line too. For anyone else who is interested the working code was as follows:

    titleNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i =0; i<self.contactarray.count; i++) {
        NSManagedObject *device = [self.contactarray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *title =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Week: %@", [device valueForKey:@"weekNo"]];
        [titleNames addObject:title];
    }

Answer (score 0):

This line here:

```
self.contactarray = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
```

This is a cardinal sin in Core Data - to not use the provided error parameters.

```
NSError *error;
self.contactarray = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                     &error] mutableCopy];

if (!self.contactArray) {
    // Fetch Requests return a nil on error, in which case you should check the error.
    NSLog(@"Error occurred: %@", error);
} else {
    // do whatever you want with the array
}
```

Now run your code and look at the console and you might see the reason for the error.

**Edited to add**

Following a comment:

You should **always** check that the return of the method is `nil` before evaluating the error object. For Cocoa (and Cocoa-Touch) methods this is the only time that the error parameter is guaranteed to be valid.

This is taken from the [Error Handling Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH204-BAJIIGCC)

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to check the error is not nil, and handle a nil result set later on in the app flow as that is not always indicative of an error?

Answer (score 0):

Just call this user-defined method. for ex -

```
self.titleNames = [self selectAllRowInEntity:@"WeightLog"];


-(NSArray *) selectAllRowInEntity:(NSString *) entityName
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fRequest;
    NSEntityDescription *eDesc;
    NSArray *arr;
    fRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    eDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fRequest setEntity:eDesc];


    arr =   [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fRequest error:nil];
    return arr;

}
```